# Get the TextView value of the gridview while clicking on an element

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to get the value of TextView from gridView, when I click on an element of the list. The adapter consists of 2 textViews. This is the ListAdapter class.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private int layout;
private ArrayList<Customer> CustomerList;

public ListAdapter(Context CustomerList, int customer_activity, ArrayList<Customer> Customer) {
    this.context = CustomerList;
    this.layout = customer_activity;
    this.CustomerList = Customer;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return CustomerList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return CustomerList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView textViewJob, textViewName;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout,null);

        holder.textViewJob = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvJobAdap);
        holder.textViewName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvNameAdap);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Customer Customer = CustomerList.get(position);

    holder.textViewJob.setText(Customer.getJob());
    holder.textViewName.setText(Customer.getName());

    return row;
}
```

}

When I click on an element of my list (for example at the third position), I would like to get the TextViewName (Customer.getName()) which corresponds to that id. I have tryed to explain it at gridViewCustomer.setOnItemClickListener in Toast.makeText

```
GridView gridViewCustomer;
ArrayList<Customer> customer;
ListeAdapter adapter = null;

public String selectedItemText;

//Referenz of the SQLiteHelper class
public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Customer_activity);


    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(CustomerListe.this, "Customer.sqlite", null, 3);
    //Customer List
    gridViewCustomer = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvCustomerList);
    customer = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ListeAdapter(this, R.layout.customer_activity, customer);
    gridViewCustomer.setAdapter(adapter);

gridViewCustomer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int position, long id) {

Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "You have clicked on the element with id =" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Please how could I get the TextView (TextViewName) corresponding to that id ?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Did you remove some partsfrom the code ? cause `customer` list  will always be empty with this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
gridViewCustomer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int position, long id) {

                 Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "You have clicked on the element with id =" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "You have clicked on the element with name=" + customer.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank @B.M for your suggestion. But it doesn't work, because the customer.get(id) returns an **int**, and the id is a **long**

Comment: @Kel can you please check the update d answer i have misstyped `position` with `id`

Comment: @Kel glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

one solution is that you can create an interface in the adapter like this

```
public interface OnAdapterItemClickListener{
   public void click(View view,int position,String name);
}
```

and a class inside adapter

```
 public void clickItem(OnAdapterItemClickListener listener){

    this.listener =listener;
}
```

define this in the adapter as variable

```
public OnAdapterItemClickListener listerner;
```

now inside your BindViewHolder

```
  holder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.click(view,position,name);
        }
    });
```

and the final step you just need to set the interface inside the class where you are using the adapter

```
  chatUsersListAdapter.clickItem(new OnAdapterItemClickListener ChatUsersListAdapter.OnItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void click(View view,int position, String name) {
            //perform any action
        }
    });
```